# Cannot navigate between routes. VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm making a gallery and I've been able to show all photos like this:[image: gallery]

When I click the button the image will be displayed to the user:

[image: Individual image]

And when I'll try to go to the next image (route) it doesn't nothing! But when I click the previous button, instead go to previous image, return to the gallery

Here's my routes:

```
  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '../views/Home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/gallery',
    name: 'Gallery',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "gallery" */ '../views/Gallery.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/gallery/photo/:img',
    name: 'Photo',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "photo" */ '../views/Photo.vue')
  }
]
```

And here's my Photo's component, where I show the selected image:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <img v-bind:src="img" alt="imagen" />
    <br />
    <button @click="previous()">Anterior</button>
    <button @click="next()" style="margin-left: 10px">Siguiente</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Photo",

  computed: {
    img: function () {
      const url = this.$route.params.img;

      return url.replaceAll("%2F", "/").replaceAll("%3F", "?");
    },
  },

  methods: {
    previous: function () {
      this.$router.go(-1);
    },

    next: function () {
      this.$router.go(1);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And here's my Photos component, where all the images are displayed and the user can choose one of them:

```
<template>
  <div id="gallery">
    <div id="photo" v-for="(img, index) in photos" alt="img" :key="index">
      <img v-bind:src="img" /><br />
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Photo', params: { img: img } }">
        <button>Visitar</button>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Photos",

  //https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517694712202-14dd9538aa97%3Fixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80

  data() {
    return {
      photos: [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517694712202-14dd9538aa97?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590608897129-79da98d15969?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1457305237443-44c3d5a30b89?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1053&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571171637578-41bc2dd41cd2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534972195531-d756b9bfa9f2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE3MzYxfQ&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80",
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I have made two methods to navigate, but I think it's wrong...

[image: methods]

[image: template with router links]

Comment: what error do you see on console

Comment: @DevCl9 I haven't no mistake in console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the behaviour of router.go [documentation link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n), it is used to browse the history, that's why you go back to the gallery on previous and why you can't use next.

I will suggest you to have:

- an array of your image urls
- the index of your current displayed image

If the current index is greater than zero, you will display a previous button linked to `imageUrls[currentImageIndex- 1]`. If the index is smaller than imagesUrls.length - 1, you will display a next button linked to `imageUrls[currentImageIndex+ 1]`.

**edit:** Use `<router-link>` with these urls instead of @click.

Tip: when you remove or add images, you need to update the currentImageIndex

(2nd Tip: Personally, I would use vuex and would put both the array and the index of the current image in a vuex store)

Comment: So... If I have in vuex (state) an array with those image's urls I will be able to pass by url parameter the index and if it's greater or smaller I display the specific button?

Comment: Vuex is not compulsory, it is just a nice tool to avoid passing props around.
I forgot to add a detail on this answer, I edited it.

Comment: But if I use router-link... How I 'redirect' to the route. I mean... I think I should use router.push(imageUrls[currentImageIndex- 1 | +1]) to navigate

Comment: You don't need all these troubles, you are making it harder for yourself. I advise you to read the vue-router documentation and/or check examples. The simplest solution would be to use the `/gallery/photo/` inside the `:to` prop of your router [and optionaly an id or an uuid from your data source (db or server) part if not a SPA]. You don't need to pass the image url as you have its url from images[currentId], you only need to change the currentId. The initial question was (*more than*) answered: `router.go navigate the history`, editing it to solve other problems is not fair.

Answer (score 1):

change the following sections:

```
<button @click="previous()">Anterior</button>
<button @click="next()" style="margin-left: 10px">Siguiente</button>
```

to

```
<button @click="previous">Anterior</button>
<button @click="next" style="margin-left: 10px">Siguiente</button>
```

remove the parenthesis after the function identifiers.